# SQL- Count number of 'similar' rows and place results in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table called of 'orders' that records an order id for a meal, a person id for the person who ordered the meal and the meal (which can be 1, 2, or 3)

```
     orders
oid | pid | meal
________________
 1  | 1   | 2
 2  | 1   | 3
 3  | 3   | 1
 4  | 5   | 2
 5  | 5   | 2
 6  | 5   | 1
```

I want to generate a result that will allow me to view the number of orders for each meal for each pid:

```
 pid | meal1 | meal2 | meal3
____________________________
 1   |   0   |   1   |  1
 3   |   1   |   0   |  0
 5   |   0   |   2   |  1
```

I am not an SQL expert, but I was thinking that I would first group the list by pid, then by meal. But how would I do the counting? I am truly lost.

Comment: This is called a pivot. However, mySQL doesn't support pivots.  So this can be accomplished using case statements and a sum.  Grouping by the meal doesn't work because you want your meal #'s to become different columns.  Using  case statements you can define a column for each each meal # and then simply evaluate if the record in question is for meal 1,2,3 and then sum up the results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you need to first create multiple columns for the different meals using case when, then you can group by pid and sum it up

```
Select pid, sum(case when meal =1 then 1 else 0 end) as meal1,
            sum(case when meal =2 then 1 else 0 end) as meal2,
            sum(case when meal =3 then 1 else 0 end) as meal3
from Table
group by pid
```

Comment: It will give the response in current context. What will happen if Meal goes on increasing to 1,2,3,4,5 then user will have to update the query every time.

Comment: Like xQbert mentioned, that can be accomplished by using pivot which is not supported in mySQL. If I faced this issue while coding, I would either use excel to generate all those case when statements or connect through SAS and use proc transpose.

Comment: sorry I am not aware of SAS and use proc transpose method. We can only generate the case statement if we know the meals before hand, if the query is used in stored procedure, this will required to be altered every time new meal is added.

Comment: I accept as this is giving answer in current context.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Vielen Dank!